# Simple POST with ASP.NET Framework

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Here is my problem, I want to receive the Username and Password of the client with `POST` request.

The code seems simple but doesn't work

The `LoginController.cs` :

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Login")]
    [Route("api/{controller}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login([FromBody] LoginJson json)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

The `LoginJson.cs` form :

```
public class LoginJson
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The `ajax` request with `jQuery`, i don't want to change the url because i want to use 3 urls `/api/Login`, `/api/Method1` and `/api/Method2` for 3 different controllers:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/api/Login',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json, charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            Username: username,
            Password: password,
        }),
        ...
});
```

The route for API, in `Global.asax.cs` :

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(...)


    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new {action = RouteParameter.Optional}
    );
}
```

I get error `404 (Not Found)`.
I will change the `Global.asax.cs` file.

Comment: `ApiController` is from ASP.NET Web API. AJAX is from AJAX. Please don't remove useful tags.

Comment: Seems like this is perfect for attribute routing. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: @mason Can you help me by suggesting your answer please? I try different possibilities like tips in your link but i still have `404 (Not found)`

Comment: The documentation I provided clearly describes how to set up attribute routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only calling the controller with no action and since there is no default action defined you'll get a 404 error.

In the jQuery you can do:

```
url: '/api/Login/Login'
```

Or change the routing by either putting this tag:

```
[Route("api/login")]
```

Or in the RouteConfig.cs, this should be done before the other routes are set including the generic one.

```
routes.MapRoute("Login", "Login/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" });
```

Comment: I don't want to change the url from jQuery, the `[ActionName("api/login")]` don't work and you forgot the last option

Comment: @Rodrigue I've added in how to add it in RouteConfig.cs

Comment: You mean set default controller to `Login` ? It's a bad idea. It'll just bring the problem back later with other `Controller` class. If I have 3 different controllers; i just want to have `/api/Login`, `/api/Action1`, `/api/Action2` as urls for my `POST` requests.

Anyway no solution works

Comment: That's not setting the default controller to `Login` for everything only when you do `/Login`. So other controller will work the same as they do. And forgot to mention you will have to put that before the other routes in `RouteConfig` otherwise the generic one will take over.

Comment: Sorry but your answer is still not enough for me, I can't get another error code than `404 (Not found)`. Can I ask you for a more complete answer please?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `api/login`

You can do like that:

```
[ActionName("api/login")]
public HttpResponseMessage Login([FromBody] LoginJson json)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: Not working. I would like to use the urls: `/api/Login`, `/api/Method1` and `/api/Method2` for 3 different controllers